# Making Emacs see ♥ as punctuation

Tags: syntax-table

I'm trying to get emacs to understand ♥ as punctuation.
`(modify-syntax-entry ?♥ "." text-mode-syntax-table)`

I'm not sure what the issue is. (That is a unicode heart.)
`(modify-syntax-entry ?\u2665 "." text-mode-syntax-table)`

For purposes of recognizing that a new sentence starts after "Hi!♥"

How can I troubleshoot this?

### Examples:

```
Lorem impsum dolor.♥ Sit amet.|
```

(where the pipe indicates the starting cursor position.)
Hitting M-a moves the cursor to the left of "Lorem".

```
Lorem impsum dolor♥. Sit amet.|
```

Hitting M-a moves the cursor to the left of "Sit".

I want both cases for it to move to the left of "Sit". In some modes.

Comment: You say nothing about the symptoms of the problem. Provide a recipe or description that shows what the problem is.

Comment: Why has the O.P. used three (3) spaces following the `.` in the NEWENTRY argument?

Comment: @lawlist: no idea why, but it does not seem to make any (?) difference - when I look at the character with `C-u C-x =` it says that the syntax is "punctuation", so the code works. It's not clear why the OP thinks that there is a problem.

Comment: I removed the extra spaces, thank you for that. I added examples of what doesn't work. I was unaware of `C-x C-x =`, which was one of the troubleshooting features I was fishing for by posting this question, but I also get "punctuation" so I don't know why it doesn't seem to be recognized as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence movement functions use the regexp returned by the `(sentence-end)` function to find the end of a sentence. The `(sentence-end)` function returns the value of the `sentence-end` variable if it is not nil. (The function and variable share the same name).

You can modify the value of the `sentence-end` variable to any regexp you want. In order to maintain all other functionallity provided by the defaults for sentence movement, I recommend you set the value of `sentence-end` to be a regexp matching either ♥ or the default return value of the `(sentence-end)` function.

Below is a function that sets the local value of the `sentence-end` variable as described.

```lisp
(defun my-setup-sentence-end ()
   "Modify the local value of the `sentence-end'
variable to be a regexp matching either ♥ or the default
regexp returned by the `sentence-end' function."
   (setq-local
    sentence-end
    (rx (or "♥" (eval (let ((sentence-end nil)) (sentence-end)))))))
```

Once you have this function you can add it as a hook to any mode you would like.

```lisp
;; For example, you can add this behavior to `text-mode' like so
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-setup-sentence-end)
```

Now you can use `(forward-sentence)`, `(backward-sentence)` and other text movemnt functions to navigate to ♥ characters. This regexp may not fit your exact use case, but should provide the basic understanding for you to create your own.

Take a look at the paragraph.el source file for more information about the modification of `sentence-end`.

Comment: Looking at evaluation of (sentence-end), it currently returns `"\\([.?!…‽][]\"'”’)}]*\\($\\|[   ]\\)\\|[。．？！]+\\)[   
]*"` and I'm not sure how the syntax-table factors into that. So weird! I think I can find a work-around to my problem by modifying `sentence-end` like you suggest.

Comment: @Sandra The solution will depend on what you want from the heart character, making emacs know that it's punctuation doesn't mean it will use it as a sentence delimiter and vice versa. What is the use case you're building for?

Comment: https://github.com/yuutayamada/auto-capitalize-el/blob/master/auto-capitalize.el

Comment: @Sandra Interesting, it looks like that package revolves mainly around the tools from paragraph.el, did this function work in conjunction with that?